# How do I use a value returned from a wxPython button in another function?

Tags: python, function, button, wxpython, return

I'm teaching myself Python/wxPython so apologies in advance for the newbie nature of my question and any incorrect terminology.

I've trawled the web and other suggested answers on here but I can't seem to find what I'm looking for.

I've got the following button that returns an open file (.txt) object:

```
def onHydroInputButton(self, event):
    dlg = wx.FileDialog(self, "Select file", self.dirname, "", "*.*", wx.OPEN)
    if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        input1 = open(dlg.GetPath())
        dlg.Destroy()
        return input1
```

I'd like to use input1 in another function. Could anybody show me how please?

```
for line in input1:
```

Obviously throws up an error that input1 is not defined.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling the function returns some data. You need to store this, e.g.:

`self.some_var = self.onHydroInputButton(event)`

Now the output of the function is stored in `self.some_var`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Must be a pain for the experts to have to answer such basic questions, it's appreciated.